# Order by promotion status ( startDate<getDate()<endDate )?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below:

```
ID    Title    StartDate    EndDate
1     PromoA   2012-06-01   2012-08-01
2     PromoB   2011-01-01   2011-02-01
3     PromoC   2012-09-01   2012-10-01
4     PromoD   2012-07-01   2012-09-01
```

So, there are 4 promotion with status: `1-OnGoing; 2-OutOfDate; 3-Waiting; 4-OnGoing`

How to sort them by their status?

Comment: are you working out the status based on ordering by startdate then enddate? What is your current query and/or expected result for the table you provided?

Comment: I expect the result as : 1-OnGoing; 4-OnGoing; 3-Waiting; 2-OutOfDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement to classify each row, as in the following (note that this assumes that `StartDate <= EndDate` for all rows:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, Title, StartDate, EndDate, 
        CASE WHEN (EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'OutOfDate' 
             WHEN (StartDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'Waiting' 
             ELSE 'Ongoing'
        END AS [Status]
    FROM Promotion
)
SELECT ID, Title, StartDate, EndDate
FROM cte
ORDER BY [Status]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE     
(    
     id int,  
     status varchar(20)  
)   

insert @table  
    SELECT  id,  
        CASE WHEN (EndDate < getdate()) THEN 'OutOfDate'  
             WHEN (StartDate > getdate()) THEN 'Waiting'  
             ELSE 'Ongoing'  
        END AS Status  
    FROM Promotion


SELECT *  
FROM Promotion p  
inner join @Table t on t.id = p.id  
ORDER BY Status
```